# Why doesn't my wallpaper show up

Tags: 13.10, 64-bit, desktop-background

I'm using ubuntu 13.10 x64, I don't know why but my wallpaper doesn't show up.
How can I fix this problem? Thanks.
[image]

I run this command: `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active true` and now I can see my wallpapter, but the system runs very slow, please see the top command:
[image]

It seems like the ibus using a lot of CPU recourse , is this normal?

Comment: Does the desktop work at all? Can you right click it?

Comment: Hi @Oli, I can not right click it, but I can run other programs OK, but program shows up very slow.

Comment: That suggests Nautilus isn't running. That's what normally manages the desktop. Does Nautilus work otherwise? Can you browse your files, etc?

Comment: I don't use Nautilus, I use nemo, because Nautilus run very slowly on my laptop, I can use Nemo to browse files, it works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from your comments, you've removed Nautilus and as I explained in my comments, Nautilus is what manages the desktop (and wallpaper) in Ubuntu.

The easiest fix is just to reinstall Nautilus. You don't have to *use* it for anything but managing the desktop.

The harder route is getting Nemo to manage your desktop. [This post](http://www.fandigital.com/2013/01/set-nemo-default-file-manager-ubuntu.html) seems to suggest that this is all that's required but I find it hard to believe:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons true
```

Comment: Thanks @Oli, I tried those command, now it seems everything is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Run the below command on terminal to enable desktop wallpaper,

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active true
```

Or

Install `Ubuntu-tweak-tool`.From that `turn on` desktop icons which in turn enables the `desktop wallpaper`.Run the below commands to install ubuntu-tweak-tool in Ubuntu 13.10,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

[image]